# Strange Nasm error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

Tags: linux, ubuntu, assembly, x86, nasm

I have an assembler file with this code:

```
global _start  
_start:
mov eax, -2

imul eax, c

mov ebx, eax

mov eax, 82

imul eax, d

sub ebx, eax

div  4

mov eax, 1
mov ebx, 0
int 0x80

section .data

a: db 10
c: db 3
d: db 2
```

I compile it with:

```
nasm -f elf c1.asm
```

I get an error:

> c1.asm:15: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands

What is the problem with my code, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Line 15 looks like `div 4`, and according to an instruction set reference [_DIV_](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/DIV.html) doesn't take an immediate operand. It takes a memory operand or a register.

Comment: To do an unsigned integer division by 4 you don't need `div` at all. Just do a logical shift 2 bits to the right: `shr eax,2`

Comment: Next time you ask about an error on a particular line, how about providing us with line numbers in the source. Or placing a comment to identify the line.

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> mov eax, -2
> imul eax, c
> mov ebx, eax
> mov eax, 82
> imul eax, d
> sub ebx, eax
>     *** Here's something amiss            
> div  4
> ```

These first 6 lines place a result in EBX, but the `div` instruction will always use the EAX register and certainly not the EBX register! You need to move the result from EBX to EAX with `mov eax, ebx` prior to doing the division.

---

> ```
> div  4
> ```

The `div` instruction doesn't take an immediate for an operand! Even if it did, you would still have to supply some info about the size of the operation.

This solution keeps the division:

```
xor edx, edx
div dword [four]  ;divide EDX:EAX by 4 -> quotient in EAX

four dd 4
```

A much better solution is to not divide at all and just shift EAX to the right 2 times:

```
shr eax, 2
```

---

> ```
> imul eax, c
> ...
> imul eax, d
> ```

These `imul`'s compiled fine but to actually multiply by the defined values use the following:

```
imul eax, [c]
...
imul eax, [d]

c dd 3
d dd 2
```